# D 1.0 (Tango) Move mouse; simulate keyboard presses etc

Tags: keyboard, cursor, d, tango

Hey, I'm using [D 1.041 with Tango 0.99.8](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/wiki/DmdDownloads) and was wondering how I would go about moving the mouse and simulating keyboard presses and getting infos from the screen, for example the color of a specific pixel on a specific coordinate. I'm using Windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I want to program a class-based library with functionality that resembles AutoIt's. For example:

```
mouse.move(100, 200);
mouse.click(2); // 2 = Middle Mouse Click
keyboard.type('abc');

import tango.sys.win32.UserGdi;

class Mouse{
    alias SetCursorPos set_pos;
    alias GetCursorPos get_pos;
    void left_click(){
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    void right_click(){
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

This code gives me the following error:

> Error 42: Symbol Undefined
>   _mouse_event@16
>   --- errorlevel 1

Any help on that? I'm still using [version](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/wiki/DmdDownloads).

Comment: This is not a D specific problem. Try to look for a C-based solution; porting that should be straightforward.

Comment: Please don't jump to conclusions so quickly. As you can see below, this is a Tango-specific problem, thus it's also D-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Tango.

Tango declares mouse_event as:

```
void mouse_event(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD);
```

while [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260(VS.85).aspx) shows that it takes 5 parameters, not 4.

For serious Win32 development you should take a look at the [Windows API bindings](http://dsource.org/projects/bindings/wiki/WindowsApi) project.